# Hexadecimal values division in C

Tags: c

I have two numbers represented in a hexadecimal format:

```
uint16_t NUM   = 0xEEEE;  // Numerator
uint16_t DENUM = 0XFFFF;  // Denominator
```

I want to have the numeric value of the division. Let us declare a `double` here:

```
double divisonResult = (double)(NUM / DENUM); // Shall be 0.9333333333333333
```

When I debug, the value of `divisonResult` is always 0.

In my case, is casting allowed or not?

Is there another way to get the wanted result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The notation is a red herring: the problem is that the cast happens *after* the integer division due to your enclosing that operation in parentheses.

Use simply

```
(double)NUM / DENUM
```

although I prefer

```
1.0 * NUM / DENUM
```

not only for clarity but in case NUM is ever changed to a wider type than a double whereupon a cast could cause truncation.

Comment: `(double)(NUM) / DENUM` seems odd. I'd use `(double)NUM / DENUM` or `((double)NUM) / DENUM` if you want to be explicit about the order.

Comment: @user694733: Personally I always use `1.0 * NUM / DENUM` but that's for another time. Worth nothing that `NUM / DENUM * 1.0` does not work.

Comment: The `1.0*` is better as it coaxes the math to resolve to the wider of math possibilities between the `double`, `1.0` and the type of `NUM`  _which may change_ in the future to say `long double`.  Casting could truncate information.